# Entropy of a Probability Measure after Push-forward

Tags: measure-theory, entropy, change-of-variable, pushforward

$\underline{\text{Is it true that the entropy of a measure is equal to the entropy of its push-forward by some measurable map?}}$

Without all the details, let $\mu$ be some probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (for simplicity let it be a density), $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d $ some measurable map, and  $f_{\#}\mu$ the push-forward of $\mu$ by $f$ :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure . The Entropy of $\mu$ is defined as

$$
H(\mu)=\int \mu \log\mu ~dx.
$$

Is it true $H(\mu)=H(f_{\#}\mu)$?

I thought so since : $f_{\#}\mu(x)=\mu \circ f^{-1}(x)$, moreover the change of variables gives

\begin{align*}
H(f_{\#}\mu)=\int f_{\#}\mu (x)\log f_{\#}\mu(x) ~dx=&\int \mu(x) \log f_{\#}\mu \circ f(x) ~dx
\\ 
=&\int \mu(x)\log \mu(x) dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you be more precise with your notation---what are you composing? Is $\mu$ in the integrand meant to denote the density of $\mu$?

Comment: Yes, its a bit lazy notation - sorry

Answer (score 1):

Not true in general. For example, if $f$ is the constant $0$ map, the density of the pushforward is not defined (but, in a limiting sense, the entropy of the pushforward is $-\infty$). Even if $f$ preserves Lebesgue measure, it's not necessarily true. Here's an example of what can go wrong: Take $f$ to be the non-injective function shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1855927/222048, and concentrate $\mu$ on a single one of the three branches. The density of $\mu$ gets stretched out, so the entropy increases.

However, if $f$ preserves Lebesgue measure in both directions then I believe the entropy is preserved. For example, in Hamiltonian dynamics, the time flow preserves volume in position-momentum phase space (Liouville's Theorem), so the Gibbs entropy remains constant. More generally, I believe this holds whenever the integrand depends on $x$ only via the density.

Comment: "More generally, I believe this holds whenever the integrand depends on x only via the density" but this is the case for the Entropy?

Comment: Yes, this is the case for entropy.

Comment: So f must preserve lebesgue measure.